# sqlite3 to postgreSQL migration issues with Rails and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite

Prior information: I have very little knowledge in Ruby on Rails and its Gems and Frameworks. So things which seem to be obvious may not be the case to me.

I need to migrate the database from `sqlite3` to `postgreSQL` in our application containing `AngularJS` in the frontend and `Ruby on Rails` with `ActiveRecord` in the backend.

I installed the Ruby Gem `pg` and changed the `database.yml` as following:

```
# This was for sqlite
#adapter: sqlite3
#database: db/gfms.sqlite3
#pool: 5
#timeout: 5000

# This is for postgreSQL
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: llqa
pool: 5
username: postgres
password: admin
host: localhost
port: 1234
timeout: 5000
schema_search_path: "gfms"
```

I'm having several issues now. Some queries return no records where they should, but don't generate an error. But:

A more specific problem I'm having is this error:

```
E, [2017-04-21T07:34:30.381466 #10961] ERROR -- : PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ..."configtables"  WHERE (parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR pare...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "configtables"  WHERE (parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR parent = 'model')
2017-04-21 07:34:30 - ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ..."configtables"  WHERE (parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR pare...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "configtables"  WHERE (parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR parent = 'model'):
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `async_exec'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `block in exec_no_cache'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:378:in `block in log'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.16/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:372:in `log'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:822:in `exec_no_cache'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:137:in `exec_query'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:954:in `select'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:24:in `select_all'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:265:in `execute_simple_calculation'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:227:in `perform_calculation'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:119:in `calculate'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.16/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:34:in `count'
        /Users/ndinatale/leanlogic-qa-prototype/server/lib/models_base.rb:135:in `get_list'
        /Users/ndinatale/leanlogic-qa-prototype/server/routes/02_rest_misc.rb:266:in `block in <top (required)>'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1611:in `block in compile!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `[]'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:994:in `route_eval'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:975:in `block (2 levels) in route!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1015:in `block in process_route'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `catch'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1013:in `process_route'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:973:in `block in route!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `each'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:972:in `route!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1085:in `block in dispatch!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1082:in `dispatch!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `block in call!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `block in invoke'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `catch'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1067:in `invoke'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:907:in `call!'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:895:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/xss_header.rb:18:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb:16:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/json_csrf.rb:18:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/base.rb:49:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-protection-1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/frame_options.rb:31:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/nulllogger.rb:9:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/show_exceptions.rb:25:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:182:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:2013:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `block in call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1785:in `synchronize'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1785:in `synchronize'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.8/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1487:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:600:in `handle_request'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `call'
        /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The function where the error happens (the line is commented):

```
def get_list(limit = nil, page = nil)
  coll = all
  coll = (block_given?) ? (yield coll) : coll
  rowcnt = coll.count # This is the line where the error happens
  pages = (limit && limit > 0) ? (rowcnt.to_f/limit).ceil : 1
  coll = coll.limit(limit) if limit && limit > 0
  coll = coll.offset((page-1)*limit) if limit && limit > 0 && page && page > 1
  ret = { rows: coll.all.to_a, rowcnt: rowcnt, page: page || 1, pages: pages, limit: limit || 0 }
  def ret.serialize(include = nil)
    self[:rows].collect! do |row|
      hash = include ? (row.serializable_hash(include: include.incllist)) : row.serializable_hash
      (hash['code'] && hash['code'].end_with?('(TR)')) ? nil : ((block_given?) ? yield(hash,row) : hash)

    end
    self[:rows].compact!
    return self.rest_success,true,self
  end
  return ret
end
```

This is just an example. My question however is: Is there something in the configuration of `ActiveRecord`, `Ruby` or `postgreSQL` itself so it behaves equally like with `sqlite3`? What needs to be done, if anything?

Comment: You don't quote strings in PostgreSQL using double quotes. Those are reserved for identifiers, like table or column name. So `parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR` is invalid. Don't know how to change it in Ruby, so just leaving this tip here.

Comment: I wonder how that query is generated? Is for example the `parent IS NULL OR parent = "" OR parent = 'model'` part hardcoded? Can you show us the code?

Comment: @spickermann You were right, it was hardcoded in a REST route call:
`q.where('parent IS NULL OR parent = '' OR parent = ?', 'model')`
So can I assume that I do not have to change some configuration of `activerecord` or something in order to run with `postgreSQL` instead of `sqlite3`?

Comment: @llqadude You don't have to change any configurations when migrating to PG, unless you're doing some database specific things in a query.

Comment: @Iceman Okay, thank you!

Comment: watch your migration carefully, I got error like this once, when migrating to pg, the problem is I create a foreign key before the model that referred is created, it works in sqlite but not in pg